# run animation then remove element

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am tring to run a simple animation then remove the div since it lies over some buttons so you can not click them after the animation.

JS

```
$(".intro").eq(0).delay(800).animate({"opacity":"0"},1000 );
```

I tried doing this to remove the element after the animation but it removes it before.

```
$(".intro").eq(0).delay(800).animate({"opacity":"0"},1000 ).remove();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove in animate function's callback:

```
$(".intro").eq(0).delay(800).animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function() {
  $(this).remove()
});
```

Alternatively, add complete function in option object:

```
$(".intro").eq(0).delay(800).animate({opacity: 0}, {duration: 1000, complete: function() {$(this).remove();}});
```

You can add more options to it, easing for example. Check the [**API doc**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[complete callback](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#complete)** to call once the animation is complete :

```
 $(".intro").eq(0).delay(800).animate({"opacity":"0"},1000, function() {
      $(this).remove();
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ro49akL/)**

Comment: Syntax wrong man.  Either wrap as option, `animate({"opacity":"0"},{duration:1000, complete:function(){
      $(this).remove();
 }});`, or remove the `complete:` part.

Answer (score 0):

Use the complete callback

```js
$(".intro").eq(0).delay(800).animate({"opacity":"0"},1000, function() { $(this).remove(); } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="intro">Hello</div>
```